# Fan command from a Fantom process Failing

Tags: cmd, fantom

I am trying to call a fan command from a Fantom process. This is the error it runs from Fantom, it runs correctly from the command line. What do you think the problem could be?

```java
class Main {
   Void main() {
       buf := Buf()

       Process() {
          command = ["fan <pod>::<type>.<method>"]
          out = buf.out 
       }.run.join

       outStr := buf.flip.readAllStr
    }   
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
sys::IOErr: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "fan <pod>::<type>.<method>": 
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
  java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (Unknown)
  fan.sys.Process.run (Process.java:141)
  PDFCommandLine::Main.main (Main.fan:10)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown)
  fan.sys.Method.invoke (Method.java:559)
  fan.sys.Method$MethodFunc.callOn (Method.java:230)
  fan.sys.Method.callOn (Method.java:139)
  fanx.tools.Fan.callMain (Fan.java:185)
  fanx.tools.Fan.executeType (Fan.java:147)
  fanx.tools.Fan.execute (Fan.java:41)
  fanx.tools.Fan.run (Fan.java:308)
  fanx.tools.Fan.main (Fan.java:346)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that there is no Windows file called `fan`, only `fan.bat`!

It is only the Windows command prompt that interpolates `fan` and looks for executable extensions, `.com`, `.bat`, `.cmd`, `.exe`, etc...

Note experience with the [BedSheet](http://eggbox.fantomfactory.org/pods/afBedSheet/) proxy tells me that the new `fan.bat` launches Java in separate process and the batch file finishes straight away; so you don't actually receive any output from the `Process` class, even though the Fantom program ran successfully.

Instead you need to compose a command that launches the Java process yourself. Something like:

```
C:\> java -cp %FAN_HOME%\lib\java\sys.jar fanx.tools.Fan <pod>::<type>.<method>
```

Here's a little snippet that does just that in a cross-plaform manner:

```java
static Process fanProcess(Str[] cmd) {
    homeDir   := Env.cur.homeDir.normalize
    classpath := (homeDir + `lib/java/sys.jar`).osPath
    args      := ["java", "-cp", classpath, "-Dfan.home=${homeDir.osPath}", "fanx.tools.Fan"].addAll(cmd)
    return Process(args)
}
```

And you can use like this:

```java
buf := Buf()
fanProcess(["<pod>::<type>.<method>", "arg1", "arg2"]) {
    out = buf.out 
}.run.join
outStr := buf.flip.readAllStr
```

Note the above requires `java` to be on your `PATH`.